# How do you Load a TextView with data from an RTF file in bundle, using Swift 5?

Tags: bundle, local, rtf

import UIKit
class TermsViewController: PopViewController {

var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

```
let fileName = "file-sample_100kB"
//https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-rtf-download/
if let rtfPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "rtf") {
  do {
    let attributedStringWithRtf: NSAttributedString = try NSAttributedString(url: rtfPath, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.rtf], documentAttributes: nil)
    self.textView.attributedText = attributedStringWithRtf
  } catch let error {
    print("Got an error \(error)")
  }
}
view.addSubview(textView)
```

}
}

There's my code to display an RTF file in a textView, but attributedStringWithRtf is nil. The url has the third RTF file that I've tried.

It is also possible to import an attributed string from text in some other standard format, such as HTML or RTF. (There are also corresponding export methods.) To import, get the target text into a Data object and call init(data:options:documentAttributes:) ; alternatively, start with a file and call init(url:options:documentAttributes:). The options: allow you to specify the source text’s format.

And that was related text from Matt Neuburg's book with his posting here: [Load Text View with data from RTF file in bundle using Swift 4 and Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618118/load-text-view-with-data-from-rtf-file-in-bundle-using-swift-4-and-xcode), but I wasn't able to post anything there, hence the new question.